# Adding domain choices to a new field in a feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, error-999999, domains

I have added a field to two news feature classes - one of the fc's is in a dataset and the other is in a database in the SDE. The new field, in each fc, needs to have three domain choices, seen in the image in the Coded Values section. [image]

But the choices that appear in the table with the dropdown arrow are , Legacy, OneFiber, and OneFiber.[image]

When I access the Subtypes tab in the feature classes, I can't do anything because it is completely greyed out. How can I add these choices?
Edit: I have now run the Create Domain tool and the Add Coded Value to Domain tool (image):

[image]
But the Assign Domain to Field tool failed. I think the problem is that I don't know how to create more than one value choice for the domain. [image]

Comment: Have you assigned the domain to the field in the feature class' properties, 'Fields' tab?

Comment: I have created the domain and added the values. My original post now has screenshots of the add coded values tool and the error message I got when I ran the Assign Domain to Field tool. Regarding the Layer Properties > Field tab, the Field Details, including Coded value domain, are all greyed out.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have discovered the solution. The field I assign the domain to apparently needs to be large enough to accommodate all the characters in all the choices combined, instead of just large enough to accommodate the largest value. I needed to run the Add Coded Value To Domain tool once each for each value. Then I ran Assign Domain to Field and all the value choices now appear in the dropdown menu of the field.